# Open Outlook Mail Profile settings w/o admin or Control Panel access?

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook

I am unable to open Outlook due to the error shown below. I don't have the admin access for this user's account. I have tried to log in via admin to configure the user's account, but still unable to. Is there any way to reset the Outlook for this user? This user is on a domain in the network for which we don't have the following access:

- Run
- CMD
- Outlook in Safe Mode
- Control Panel

[image: Outlook Error: Cannot open your default e-mail folders. Outlook cannot start because a data file to send and receive message cannot be found.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accessing Outlook Mail Setting w/o Control Panel Access

#### Solution 1

If Outlook is setup as your default mail program and it listed main part of the Start Menu, you should be able to right click it from the Start Menu and select *Properties*. From there you should be to edit, add, and remove the the user's mail profile.

#### Solution 2

You will need access to the Windows Mail applet. It is where you can edit the mail profile as suggested by the error. Since you do not have Control Panel access you need to locate the Control Panel extension for the Outlook mail and try opening it.

You should be able access it by opening the **System32** folder within **Windows** folder then searching for `mlcfg32.cpl`. Once you find `mlcfg32.cpl`, try opening it by double clicking it. If it doesn't allow you too, try right-clicking it, selecting *Run-As*, and running it with your admin credentials. After it is open, all you need to do is edit the user's Mail profile and relaunch Outlook.

*For Outlook 64-bit: Search for `mlcfg.cpl` within the **Windows\SysWOW64** folder.*

Comment: Is there any answer to this for latest version of Microsoft 365 Apps? Sadly, neither of these solutions look to work with the latest version anymore.